# Using the Flexigrid plugin for jQuery on an HTML table, not on XML file

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, flexigrid

I trying to use the [Flexigrid](http://flexigrid.info/) plugin for jQuery which seems perfect for what I am being asked to do to do.

Now what I'm working with is an HTML table, and I don't have the ability to change it. The above site has three examples. The first two seem to apply the Flexgrid to existing tables, which is what I need, but they do not have the sorting option.

This is the code given for the first:

```
$('.flexme').flexigrid();
```

with the HTML table being:

```
<table class="flexme">
    <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="100">Col 1</th>
                <th width="100">Col 2</th>
                <th width="100">Col 3 is a long header name</th>
                <th width="300">Col 4</th>
            </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>This is data 1 with overflowing content</td>
                <td>This is data 2</td>
                <td>This is data 3</td>
                <td>This is data 4</td>
            </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

And I thought I could simply add the following:

```
{sortable : true}
```

, ending up with:

```
$('.flexme').flexigrid( {sortable : true});
```

But this does not work.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

After digging, I found and use an extra JS library named : jquery.tablesorter that you can find here :  http://tablesorter.com/

It work then with flexigrid on a transparent way. I didn't test all possibilities, But it seems to work for the basic sorting.

Here my sample code follow. 
 You will need to change some path to the different libraries

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Channels List</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="flexigrid/css/flexigrid.pack.css" />
<script type="text/javascript"  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="flexigrid/js/flexigrid.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="tablesorter/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $("#MyTable1").tablesorter(); 
    } 
); 
</script>
</head>

<body>

<br><b><u>Channels List</b></u><br>
<table id='MyTable1' class="flexme">
    <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="100">Col1</th>
                <th width="100">Col2</th>
                <th width="100">Col3</th>
                <th width="300">Col4</th>
            </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>This is data 1a</td>
                <td>This is data 2a</td>
                <td>This is data 3a</td>
                <td>This is data 4a</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>This is data 1b</td>
                <td>This is data 2b</td>
                <td>This is data 3b</td>
                <td>This is data 4b</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>This is data 1c</td>
                <td>This is data 2c</td>
                <td>This is data 3c</td>
                <td>This is data 4c</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>This is data 1d</td>
                <td>This is data 2d</td>
                <td>This is data 3d</td>
                <td>This is data 4d</td>
            </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.flexme').flexigrid({
        title: 'This is a my test',
        height:150,striped:false, 
        }
        );
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```